# Angular Lazy Routes and optional matrix parameters

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Angular 6

I'm using a global optional matrix parameter to dynamicaly switch languages with ngx-translate: my-app/#some-component;lang=it

This code used to work before I introduced lazy loading of all the apps modules

app.component.ts

```
this.router.events.subscribe((event: Event) => {
  if (event instanceof RoutesRecognized) {
    const params = event.state.root.firstChild.params;
    const lang = params['lang'];
    if (lang) {
      this.languageService.changeLanguage(lang);
    }
  }
});
```

With lazy loading, the params variable is empty. I can't figure out how to get the desired functionality back.

This is also not working (empty):

```
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => console.log(params));

this.activatedRoute.url.subscribe(segments => {
  segments.forEach(segment => console.log(segment.parameterMap.keys));
});
```

I'm out of ideas and need some help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research I found a solution.

It looks ugly, though

```
this.router.events.pipe(
  filter(event => event instanceof RoutesRecognized)
).subscribe((event: RoutesRecognized) => {
  event.state.root.children.forEach(child => {
    child.children.forEach(c => {
      const params = c.params;
      // do stuff
    });
  });
});
```